# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a web application with Spring MVC. I started by developing the web application after I'm trying to add Spring Security; but I have this message, and I don't find a solution.

```
16-04-2010 12:10:22:296 6062 ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/generic/GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:770)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:398)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:474)
    at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:301)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/generic/GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.determineUrlsForHandler(DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:57)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a JAR - "NoClassDefFoundError"

Comment: If you are using Maven, which version of spring / spring-security are you using ?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13363083/715269

Answer (score 1):

It is because of Spring libraries version mismatch, Check this link [Issue on Spring mvc when upgrading from Spring 2.5.5 to Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991750/issue-on-spring-mvc-when-upgrading-from-spring-2-5-5-to-spring-3)

Answer (score 0):

Check versions of Spring Security in your JAR files. Spring Security has moved some classes since version 3. Check the table [here](https://www.packtpub.com/article/migration-to-spring-security-3).