# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' : MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring, maven-2

ANY advice would be apprecated. I'm stumped...

**Problem**

On my laptop, anytime our application tries to load the application-config.xml, I get a java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException.

The EXACT same code works on my desktop and my coworker's desktop/laptop.  But on my laptop it throws this error.  Since my laptop and desktop are the exact same development environment (Java 1.6 Maven project in Eclipse on Mac OS X Leopard), I've narrowed down the causes by doing the following:

- Checked out a fresh project from Subversion (so no code differences)
- Copied over and replaced my entire Eclipse directory (so no Eclipse version/plugin differences)
- Copied over and replaced my entire .m2 directory (so no maven/project dependency differences)

What could possibly be causing this error in one place but not the other?  Below is a snippet of the related beans and error...

---

**Snippet: application-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

...
    <bean id="dataServiceRepository" class="com.saic.gnosis.dao.DataServiceDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
...
    <bean id="implementationRepository" class="com.saic.gnosis.dao.ImplementationDao">
    <property name="dataServiceRepository" ref="dataServiceRepository" />
    <property name="implementationDetailRepository" ref="implementationDetailRepository" />
    <property name="implementationStrategyFactory" ref="implementationStrategyFactory" />
    </bean>
...
    <bean id="implementationStrategyFactory" class="com.saic.gnosis.plant.ImplementationStrategyPlant" />
...
    <bean id="implementationDetailRepository" class="com.saic.gnosis.dao.ImplementationDetailDao">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
...
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.saic.gnosis.model</value>
            <value>com.saic.gnosis.model.observable</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</prop> <!-- Minimum number of Connections a pool will maintain at any given time. -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">9</prop> <!-- Maximum number of Connections a pool will maintain at any given time. -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">10</prop> <!-- Seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. 
                Zero means idle connections never expire. -->
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</prop> <!-- The size of c3p0's global PreparedStatement cache. If both maxStatements 
                and maxStatementsPerConnection are zero, statement caching will not be enabled. 
                If maxStatements is zero but maxStatementsPerConnection is a non-zero value, 
                statement caching will be enabled, but no global limit will be enforced, 
                only the per-connection maximum. maxStatements controls the total number 
                of Statements cached, for all Connections. If set, it should be a fairly 
                large number, as each pooled Connection requires its own, distinct flock 
                of cached statements. As a guide, consider how many distinct PreparedStatements 
                are used frequently in your application, and multiply that number by maxPoolSize 
                to arrive at an appropriate value. Though maxStatements is the JDBC standard 
                parameter for controlling statement caching, users may find c3p0's alternative 
                maxStatementsPerConnection more intuitive to use. -->
        </props>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://database.com/ourProject" />
            <property name="user" value="ourUser" />
            <property name="password" value="ourPass" />
            <property name="initialPoolSize" value="4" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

---

**Snippet: JUnit Error Trace:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.saic.gnosis.updater.task.ConnectionCommandFileWriterTask.<init>(ConnectionCommandFileWriterTask.java:16)
        at com.saic.gnosis.updater.CiscoDeviceConfiguratorTest.initializeSpyObjects(CiscoDeviceConfiguratorTest.java:120)
        at com.saic.gnosis.updater.CiscoDeviceConfiguratorTest.initializeTestObjects(CiscoDeviceConfiguratorTest.java:110)
        at com.saic.gnosis.updater.CiscoDeviceConfiguratorTest.setUp(CiscoDeviceConfiguratorTest.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'implementationRepository' defined in class path resource [beans/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataServiceRepository' while setting bean property 'dataServiceRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataServiceRepository' defined in class path resource [beans/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans/application-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.saic.gnosis.dao.BeanDao.<clinit>(BeanDao.java:35)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataServiceRepository' defined in class path resource [beans/application-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans/application-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [beans/application-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:122)
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:82)
        at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:794)
        at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(GenericTypeResolver.java:161)
        at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveReturnType(GenericTypeResolver.java:99)
        at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:138)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:386)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1289)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        ... 70 more
```

---

EDIT:

Update - I just found another clue, none of our database-related JUnit tests work.  On my desktop they all pass.  On my laptop, they all fail with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Collection;)V
```

Any and all suggestions welcome!  Thanks!

Comment: I think as @Bozho and others. I know isn't probable, but are you sure both CLASSPATH environment variables are the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would assume you have wrong spring jars - perhaps one for spring 2.5 and one for 3.0. The classloader loads, say, spring-core for version 3.0, and the rest for 2.5. This would result in such errors.

I'd suggest going through your maven dependency graph and remove all redundant ones. If necessary, use `<exclusions>` in your pom.

Before that clean your project on all machines.

Comment: I thought about that too. But why is the behavior not consistent with the other machines?

Comment: @Pascal - it might be that the build has not been cleaned-up there recently. Or (that's a wild guess) the classloader of the Mac JVM is loading the jars in different order.

Comment: is likely on the right track; the method it's complaining about - the constructor InjectionMetadata(Class, Collection) - only exists in 3.0.

Comment: Well, there is clearly a ghost somewhere. I just fail to see where it can be.

Comment: Turns out, to put it in simplified terms, the code was being compiled and executed with two different classpaths. Of course, the actual issue was several orders of magnitude more complex. When I manually compiled and ran the JUnit test, it worked perfectly! The basic problem was, the AspectJ plugin was handling compilation with its classpath while my run configuration from JUnit was using an ever-so-subtly different classpath (and version of the spring jars). The run configurations (not under version control, by default) were the one thing that were slightly different across both machines.

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar error when trying to run Mule service on Mule ESB embedded in Tomcat. The solution was to change JDK from default:

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.1) (6b18-1.8.1-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

to good old Sun JDK:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

of course, it might have been version/patch issue. If only I had the time to investigate...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems and another measure helped: delete the whole .metadata folder. Later import projects from their place or checkout them from the svn(if you use some). The problem is that we don't really know, what metadata are broken, so the natural next step is to delete all of them. I think, it is the deepest possible cleaning apart from reinstallation of Eclipse + plugins.