# Error creating bean with name in spring

Tags: java, spring

(Spring newbie so apologies in advance for any obvious errors) 
Trying to create a authentication page using Spring. Get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JDBCLoginDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.project.shoppingcart.dao.jdbc.JDBCLoginDAOImpl.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:84)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

=====

Here is my app-context.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <description>Example configuration to get you started.</description>

    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.project.shoppingcart" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.project.shoppingcart." />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver_class}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

=======

Here is my JDBCLoginDAOImpl.java:

```
@Repository
public class JDBCLoginDAOImpl implements LoginDao {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private SimpleJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        jdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public boolean validateUser(String Username, String Password) {
        int count = 0;
        String query = "select count(*) from products where username = "+Username+
                "and password = "+Password;
        count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(query);
        if (count > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/13363083/715269

Comment: Please include your web.xml, imports of your JDBCLoginDAOImpl and the code that uses your JDBCLoginDAOImpl. BTW, why are you declaring 2 transaction managers?

Comment: Can you verify that your database connecter i.e. if your  is added as a dependency to the project.

if your driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
you should have a corresponding mysql-connecter-java library for your project

Answer (score 1):

Your setup looks almost correct to me, the only bothersome bit I can find is this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.project.shoppingcart" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.project.shoppingcart." />
```

This is a double component scan, I am pretty sure the above two statements are equal (at least they both match sub packages of shoppingcart, possible they also both match shoppingcart). Anyway, you are creating several beans multiple times. I'd start by cleaning that up (lose one of them) and perhaps your problem will go away.

Comment: tried removing the second line and just left the first one, still see the same error

Comment: @springnoob ok, but it was worth a try. :-(

Comment: @springnoob the only other thing I can think of is that you somehow have two versions of javax.sql.DataSource on your classpath

Comment: Another thing: you have two TransactionManager declarations (remove one) but no `<tx:annotation-driven />`. There's no point of having a transaction manager if you are not using it.

Answer (score -1):

change

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

by:

```
@Autowired
private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
```

and add the import:

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

and adjust the getter and setter

Comment: the class DriverManagerDataSource implement the DataSource interface, so you dont have problem.