# How to use AMQ PooledConnectionFactory with spring integration?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I am using activemq 3.7 and activemq pool 3.7 libraries integrated with spring integration 2.1.3 and spring 3.0.5. When i tried to define connectionFactory like this i got the exception below

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
            destroy-method="stop">
            <property name="connectionFactory">
                <bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop">
                    <constructor-arg name="brokerURL" value="${jms.broker.url}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Here is the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource 
[META-INF/integration-context.xml]: 
Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory#1445748' 
of type [org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory] 
while setting bean property 'targetConnectionFactory'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory#1445748' 
defined in class path resource [META-INF/integration-context.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
```

if i use ActiveMQConnectionFactory instead of PooledConnectionFactory everything is deployed fine but i have performace i have performance issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971219/error-creating-bean-with-name-sessionfactory-malformedparameterizedtypeexcep

Answer (score 0):

First: Can you show the rest of the stacktrace as well as the value of your "jms.broker.url" property?

Second: there's really no need to use the "pooled" CF if you are wrapping with Spring's "caching" CF

Answer (score 0):

Spring throws exception with unbounded wildcard method:

```
public ObjectPoolFactory<?> getPoolFactory() {
    return null;
}
```

Have not found a solution yet though.