# MalformedParameterizedTypeException on SqlSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Hello my problem is confuguration mybatis- spring

### this is my dispatch-servlet of spring

```
<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.aieap" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aieap.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aieap.services" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aieap.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aieap.dao.impl" />

<!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="/WEB-INF/db.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlMap" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath*:com/aieap/conf/configuration.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="comuniDao" class="com.aieap.dao.impl.ComuniDAO">
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlMap" />
</bean>


<!-- SPRING MVC STUFF -->
<!-- Enables POJO @Controllers (like CartController) -->


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<!-- Enables annotated methods on POJO @Controllers (like CartController) -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />


<!-- Configurazione Spring MVC View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- Flow Handler Adapter -->
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<!-- Flow Handler Mapping -->
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
</bean>

<!-- Flow Executor -->
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" />

<!-- Flow Registry -->
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
    <!-- nonaut -->
    <webflow:flow-location id="home-nonaut" path="/WEB-INF/flows/nonaut/home-nonaut.xml" />
    <webflow:flow-location id="logout" path="/WEB-INF/flows/nonaut/logout.xml" />

    <!-- aut -->
    <webflow:flow-location id="aut/home-aut" path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/home-aut.xml" />
    <webflow:flow-location id="aut/nuova-domanda" path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/nuova-domanda.xml" />
    <webflow:flow-location id="aut/invia-domanda" path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/invia-domanda.xml" />
    <webflow:flow-location id="aut/nuovo-operatore-rer" path="/WEB-INF/flows/aut/nuovo-operatore-rer.xml" />

</webflow:flow-registry>

<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" />

<bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="viewResolver" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="useSpringBeanBinding" value="true" />
</bean>
```

this is the error:

```
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlMap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatch-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971219/error-creating-bean-with-name-sessionfactory-malformedparameterizedtypeexcep

Comment: but i have already tried. this is my lib

Comment: this is my spring library

com.springsource.org.ognl-2.6.9.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
mybatis-3.0.4.jar
mybatis-spring-1.0.0.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
org.springframework.binding-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.faces-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.webflow-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc.jar
spring.jar