# Unable to deploy Grails Application in Tomcat : MalformedParameterizedTypeException on 'pluginManager'

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, war

I just created a grails application (Grails 2.2.0) and I built the war file to deploy it in an apache tomcat but I just can't start the application :

this is actually my Catalina.out

> http://pastebin.com/YiWPCqHZ <-- catalina.out logs

and my BuildConfig.Groovy file:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.0"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.RC2"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"
        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
       // compile ':db-reverse-engineer:0.5'
        compile ':shiro:1.1.4'
        compile ':jxl:0.54'
        compile ":facebook-sdk:0.4.8"
        compile ":twitter4j:0.3.2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971219/error-creating-bean-with-name-sessionfactory-malformedparameterizedtypeexcep

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar exception but I am not sure if my solution will work for you as well. My problem was that a dependency (in my case http-builder) depends on an older Groovy version. Thus, I had two different versions of Groovy in WEB-INF/lib of the war file. After adding an exclusion in BuildConfig.groovy (see below) the problem disappeared.

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes 'groovy'
}
```