# Issue on Spring mvc when upgrading from Spring 2.5.5 to Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I upgraded the module of my project to use spring 3 instead of spring 2.5.5.

```
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/generic/GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:286)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:772)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:739)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:520)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:412)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:400)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:474)
            at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:51)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:97)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:68)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4071)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4375)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:790)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:770)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5312)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
            at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
            at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy43.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
            at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
            at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
            at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
            at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
            at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
            at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
            at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
            at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/generic/GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.determineUrlsForHandler(DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java:113)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:79)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:57)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
            at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:69)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:109)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:88)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
            ... 157 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
            at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:306)
            at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
            at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
            ... 168 more
        ERROR 2012-12-20 15:35:54,756 (main:) [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/oxidemo]] Servlet /oxidemo threw load() exception
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor
            at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:306)
            at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
            at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.determineUrlsForHandler(DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.java:113)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:79)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:57)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
            at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:69)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:109)
            at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:88)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:286)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.createDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:772)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:739)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerMappings(DispatcherServlet.java:520)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:412)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:400)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:474)
            at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:51)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:97)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:68)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4071)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4375)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:790)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:770)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5312)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
            at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
            at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
            at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
            at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy43.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
            at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
            at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:87)
            at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
            at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy44.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
            at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
            at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
            at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
            at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
            at
```

My module is using spring mvc.  I read that this class is removed in spring 3 but could not find if anyone had similar errors and were is it moved to.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using any other spring framework (security, integration) ?

Comment: Have you checked the Spring 2.5.x to 3.x migration guide? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/upgrade/spring3/html/

Comment: @soulcheck No just mvc, no security or integration

Comment: @Jonathan I did check and found only "Class org.springframework.beans.factory.generic.GenericBeanFactoryAccessor removed [8001]", but that does not tell me much, do you know where to find more on this, maybe this [8001] is some key for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of guess but perhaps you're still pulling in some `Spring 2.5.5` jars that expect `GenericBeanFactoryAccessor` to be present? I would double-check that you only have `Spring 3.x` jars on your classpath.

If you're using something like Maven you can invoke:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to see all your dependencies.

Like I said it's a bit of a guess, but I hope it helps!

Comment: You might be right. This is some old legacy project with no dependency management tool so I was replacing jar files manually. If this is the case it will be very hard to determine is there some jar that depends on that removed GenericBeanFactoryAccessor, but I hope this si not the case. I replaced all spring*.jar one by one, will take another look.

Comment: I will vote this as a solution since the problem was in some leftover spring jars in project and this answer pointed that this might be the issue. It was hard to find it since there is no dependency management tool.